# jquery each() & append() function not working

Tags: jquery

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this `.each()` function is not working. Seems pretty straight forward

```
function getThumbnail() {
    $('.carousel-focus-item').each(function() {
        var videoId = $(this).data('embed');
        $(this).append('<img src="//img.youtube.com/vi/' + videoId + '/hqdefault.jpg />');
        console.log(this);
    });
}
```

any ideas?

```
<div class="carousel-focus-items">
    <div class="carousel-focus-item" data-embed="hGQkp4K05kE">

    </div>
    <div class="carousel-focus-item" data-embed="EtNw4wLL5oQ">

    </div>
    <div class="carousel-focus-item" data-embed="_bZj_yxfACw">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML code.

Comment: @Eddie added HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing closing `"` on your image source.

```
 $('.carousel-focus-item').each(function() {
    var videoId = $(this).data('embed');
    $(this).append( '<img src="//img.youtube.com/vi/' + videoId + '/hqdefault.jpg" />' );
});
```

---

Here is a fiddle:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 getThumbnail();
});

function getThumbnail() {
    $('.carousel-focus-item').each(function() {
        var videoId = $(this).data('embed');
        $(this).append( '<img src="//img.youtube.com/vi/' + videoId + '/hqdefault.jpg" />' );
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-focus-items">
  <div class="carousel-focus-item" data-embed="hGQkp4K05kE">

  </div>
  <div class="carousel-focus-item" data-embed="EtNw4wLL5oQ">

  </div>
  <div class="carousel-focus-item" data-embed="_bZj_yxfACw">

  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: oh FFS! ...punched her own face!